# Pgfplots and histogram with heterogeneous values

Tags: pgfplots

I've got to plot an histogram with pgfplots where a single x value assumes a large value on the y-axis (14000) while the remaining data are all under 150... I'd like some suggestions on how to handle the plotting. I would like to have the plot scaled in order to have a good view of those data under 150 but at the same time it should report the largest value... Any suggestion?

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{figure}
    \begin{center}
        \definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.00000,0.44700,0.74100}%
        %
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        scale only axis,
        xmin=0,
        xmax=10,
        xmajorgrids,
        ymin=0,
        ymax=20000,
        ymajorgrids
        ]
        \addplot[ycomb,color=mycolor1,solid,mark=o,mark options={solid}] plot            table[row sep=crcr] {%
            0   20000\\
            1   126.220647721184\\
            2   136.394614023852\\
            3   21.1680012089801\\
            4   113.520374296189\\
            5   143.838641199471\\
            6   41.9123247298389\\
            7   98.5479898078184\\
            8   148.403736993507\\
            9   61.8177727862635\\
            10  81.6031666334055\\
        };
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    \end{center}
    \end{figure}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) with some example data to play with? Also, have you considered an axis break somewhere above 150?

Comment: Yes, logarithms!

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not an MWE. Could you please expand it according to the link I posted above?

Comment: I added a MWE.... I think I should use axis y discontinuity

Comment: Only change the `axis` to `semilogyaxis` or add the option `ymode=log` and you'll see one suggestion.

Comment: Yes, log scale improves the graph... Indeed I gave +1 to percusse (thanks!) but I would like a linear scale with an axis break (if it is possible of course!)...

Comment: The you may check out [this search](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=break+axis). Tell us if any improvement demanded.